# How can I use a stored procedure to Create Master Child recursive structure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have three related five tables parent child and another table which store information about items in child table.

Here are my tables:

Parent table

```
  Parent Item ID   PARENT Description       width     Parent item Thickness
    500200          500200 Description        15              20
    500201          500201 Description1       5               2
    500202          500202 Description2       1.5            16
    500203          500203 Description3       15             20
```

child Table

```
Parent Item ID    Item ID    Quantity     
   500200       100200      1
   500200       400200      1
   500200       300200      1
   300200       100200      1
```

child items Detail Table looks like as follows

The table stores Item = 100200 is in table X, Item = 400200 is in table Y and Item = 300200

Table X

```
Item ID  DECRIPTION  THICKNESS  DIAMETER    WIDTH  
100200   100200DESC    0.15     1.5           5
```

Table Y

```
Item ID  DECRIPTION     NAME       SIZE    
400200   400200DESC     XYZ       4X6
```

Table z

```
Item ID  DECRIPTION     NAME       SIZE    offset
300200   300200DESC     XYZ       3X9      0.375
```

What am trying to accomplish is to create a Bill of Material structure or parent to child recursive structure using C#.

I would like to create a SQL Server view or stored procedure which as shown below.

I would like to see something like this: all columns from the parent table, child, and some columns from tables X, Y, Z based on parent child relation.

```
      parent ID  PARENT Description  Parent Thickness   Item ID    Quantity     child DECRIPTION     THICKNESS    offset     SIZE
        500200     500200 Description     20             100200      1         100200DESC                 0.15
        500200     500200 Description     20             400200      1         400200DESC                                      4X6
        500200     500200 Description     20             300200      1         300200DESC                             0.375
        300200     300200 Description     20             100200      1         100200DESC                0.15                  3X9
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty basic select from either parent table or child table with left joins to all the rest of the tables...  (generally "item" would be the main table, since some items may not have parents, but any "parent" should have at least 1 child or it's not a parent.  Often, parentID is a pointer back to another itemID in the same table.)  Also, your approach of creating the tree itself outside of SQL is generally the right one when possible.

Comment: @ebyrobmy main problems getting information from tables X,Y,Z based on the child table Item Id field, displaying theses information with the parent information. I can get the tree to work i already have the parent child relation. getting fields in X,Y,Z is my challenge

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for multiple rows per single items, each row with different values.  You could try:

```
SELECT 
  childTable.ParentItemID,
  parentTable.ParentDescription,
  childTable.ItemID,
  childTable.Quantity,
  fields.Description,
  fields.Name,
  fields.Value
FROM childTable
LEFT JOIN parentTable ON childTable.ParentItemID = parentTable.ParentItemID
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT ItemID, Description, "THICKNESS" AS Name, THICKNESS AS Value FROM TableX
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ItemID, Description, "SIZE", SIZE FROM TableY
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ItemID, Description, "offset", offset FROM TableZ
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ItemID, Description, "DIAMETER", DIAMETER FROM TableX
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ItemID, Description, "WIDTH", WIDTH FROM TableX
) AS fields ON fields.ItemID = childTable.ItemID
ORDER BY childTable.ParentItemID, childTable.ItemID, fields.Name
```

This can be altered with more columns and less rows by adjusting the union selects.

Of course, when I deal with "dynamic" extra values tied to a basic table, I usually create just one detail table as in:

```
DetailTable:
  ItemID
  DetailTypeID
  DetailValue
```

Of course, if you do want a bunch of details as columns in a single row, it can take some effort this way.